# Can I use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to sync between Mac and iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I am porting my iOS app over to Mac OS (Mountain Lion) for sale in the Mac App Store in the near future.

The iOS app uses iCloud syncing with NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore which was very simple to implement and works very well. I was wondering if it would be possible to access the data stored by the iOS app in Mac OS. The user defaults between the apps are identical so this should work very well as long as it is possible to do it. Can a Mac app access iCloud NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore data stored by an iOS app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the same store identifier (defined by `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` entitlement), yes.

In fact, you can share the same store identifier between different apps on iOS devices and Mac OS X. The only restriction is that you need to have the same TEAM id for all apps since the `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier` entitlement always starts with this id.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I read that but I wasn't sure if it applied across platforms or not. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Note that when using Catalyst will the default identifier be different between Mac and iOS, since the bundle identifiers are different.